# How to upload a text file into a dictionary (in Python)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a algorithm that makes personalised book recommendations to users, which predicts which books a user is likely to enjoy, based on their peers' scores.

The two text files used for interpretation are "ratings.txt" and "books.txt", which are represented as follows:

*ratings.txt*
"Ben5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 Moose5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0..." (representative of two users)

*books.txt*
"Douglas Adams,The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy
Richard Adams,Watership Down
Mitch Albom,The Five People You Meet in Heaven
Laurie Halse Anderson,Speak
Maya Angelou,I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings" (four books and authors represented)

The rating system goes from -5(really disliked it) to 0(didn't read it) to 5(really liked it)

How would I upload these two files into Python as dictionaries to be used for this similarity algorithm?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would be the type of keys/values of that dictionary?

Comment: The keys should be the names of the users (eg.Ben), and the values be the numbers that follow.

Comment: You asked one question and you have a number of answers.  You then added a second question.  You need to separate the two and mark as accepted and or useful one or more of these answers and then ask a second question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file, iterate over lines, [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each line by space. The key would be the item with 0 index, value - the list of items with index 1 and more:

```
data = {}
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_data = line.split()
        data[line_data[0]] = line_data[1:]

print data
```

prints:

```
{'Ben5': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '-3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '-5', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '5', '5', '5', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '-5'], 
 'Moose5': ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '3', '0', '5', '0', '3', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '-3', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '3', '0', '0']}
```

Also, if you want numbers as integers:

```
data[line_data[0]] = map(int, line_data[1:])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this was put out when using the above code:

"{'ender': [], 'Leah': [], 'Jim': ['C'], 'Cust6': [], 'Cust7': [], 'Cust4': [], 'Cust5': [], 'Cust2': [], 'Cust3': [], 'Cust1': [], 'Francois': [], 'Cust8': [], 'Cust9': [], 'clipper': [], 'Ella': [], 'Iren': [], '0': ['0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '-3', '-3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '5', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']..."

Comment: @user3052287 ok, then you should provide more test input data.

Comment: Would you like the whole text document? It's rather long, which is why I only put two users.

Comment: @user3052287 well, according to the output you've provided, the contents and structure of the file is not always like the two lines you've provided.

Comment: @user3052287 - probably your input is not structured as you described above. From your output it seems users are not separated by lines and some data are probably broken into separate lines thus the printout ended up with a user named "0". Our assumption is that a line begins with user and everything after it are his data. Send a representative of those irregular inputs.

Comment: I've updated my question - I hope it's easier to understand. If you need more details, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided so little but need to start somewhere.  I am assuming that your file the words are keys and the rest are values that are to be stored in a list  I don't see new lines if each observation is defined by a newline then alecxe's solution works

I am modifying this to read in your input file as a string and I added a strip() method to each step to make sure the line breaks were accounted for

```
from collections import defaultdict

test = open(someFile).read()  # this 

mydict = defaultdict(list)
from collections import defaultdict
for item in test.split():
    try:
        x = int(item.strip())
        mydict[currentKey].append(x)
    except ValueError:
        currentKey = item.strip()
        mydict[currentKey] = []


defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Ben5': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, -5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, -5], 'Moose5': [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5, 0, 3, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, -3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0]})
```

Comment: Perhaps I should revise what I am trying to do - I shall update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using regular expression with [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

### assume read all lines from a file
input = '''Ben5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 Moose5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 9

Moos7 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0'''

output = {}
for (key, val) in re.findall("([a-zA-Z]\w+)\s+(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)", input, re.M):
    output[key] = val

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will help solve this problem.

You are looking for two different patterns -

```
import re
s = "Ben5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 Moose5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0"

name = '(\D+)'
ratings = '((?:-?\d\s)+)'
```

Put those together and the overall pattern will result in a match with two groups.  When performing a lot of matches with a single pattern it may be worth compiling the pattern -

```
pattern = name + ratings
regex = re.compile(pattern)
```

You can iterate over matches in the string and construct a dictionary *piecemeal* -

```
d = dict()

for match in regex.finditer(s):
    name, ratings = match.groups()
    print name, ':', ratings
    print '*'*8
    d[name] = ratings

print d

>>> 
Ben : 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 
********
Moose : 5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 
********
{'Moose': '5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 ', 'Ben': '5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 '}
```

Or you can construct the dictionary *all at once* -

```
d = dict(regex.findall(s))
```